# "NG NS" on ticket after airport security

Tags: air-travel, airport-security, tsa

I went through security at the Sacramento Airport with a friend. He got something written on his boarding pass "NG NS". I didn't have that. We both went through the same metal detector, neither beeped nor had random checks. Flying to Edmonton through Seattle connection. Early for flight.

I have tried searching for "what is tsa ng ns" on Google but nothing useful came up. Any ideas?

Comment: At what point did he get it written on the boarding pass? Check in? Metal detector?

Comment: @MarkMayo Just before the conveyor belts: Airport Entrance > airline checkin area > lineup for security > officer at the desk. Hope that makes sense, I couldn't figure out how to explain it better :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I searched around a lot and it seems it's just [TSA](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/practical-travel-safety-security-issues/1786456-ng-ns-marked-boarding-pass.html) that marks [notes](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/qyua8/what_does_the_tsa_write_on_boarding_passes/) on boarding [passes](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/checkpoints-borders-policy-debate/1158986-what-point-tsa-marking-your-bp.html), with no effect on actual security procedure as you noted, unlike the [SSSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secondary_Security_Screening_Selection) note for example.

In this case NG NS could be the inspector's initials, the checkpoint you just passed or checks they've validated.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much. I actually just went flying again recently and the officer marked my ticket, so thanks again for clarifying